# Como pintar un arreglo de datos dentro de una misma celda usando FPDF en php

Tags: php, fpdf

Buen dia compañeros recurriendo a su eterna sabiduria, tengo el siguiente problema
haciendo un formato de responsivas tengo el siguiente inconveniente, ya que cada responsiva tiene cierto numero de roles por usuario. pintando los datos no hay problema, pero al momento de querer plasmar  todos sus roles dentro del mismo recuadro me viene el problema

por que no lo pinta

intente de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
     $roles = ['Lectura','Escritura','Carga','descarga'];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($roles_acceso) ; $i++) { 
      
       $a = $roles_acceso[$i]['nombre_rol'];
     }
    $pdf->MultiCell(30,10,utf8_decode($a),1,'C',0);
?>
```

Despues de que lo pongo asi, solo me muestra el primer objeto de la lista y ya no muestra mas.

Alguien que tenga una mejor idea o que me diga como hacerlo...

Resolviendo el problema ya quedo asi

```
<?php
  $a ='';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($roles_acceso) ; $i++) { 
      
       $a .= "-".$roles_acceso[$i]['nombre_rol']."\n";
     }
    $pdf->MultiCell(30,5,utf8_decode($a),1,'C',0);
```

Comment: Mi PHP está MUY oxidado peeero... esa condición del for no es contra el length/size de $roles_acceso?

Comment: no, la sintaxis esta bien, si corre bien

Comment: No es que sea la sintaxis, el intérprete de PHP no se va a quejar. Lo que digo es que ese count sí da el valor que esperas? Lo otro, cómo es el contenido de $roles_acceso cuando haces `print_r($roles_acceso)`? No es evidente que usar el indice $i funcione como esperas porque no conocemos los datos. Recuerda [edit] la pregunta para ampliarla en estos detalles

Comment: si te entiendo, si da el conteo esperado

Comment: Lo otro es que el for sólo asigna el valor de $a, N veces, y pdf->MultiCell sólo va a tener EL ÚLTIMO valor de $a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de todo lo que acertadamente te indica @Alfabravo, prueba así:

```
<?php
    $roles = ['Lectura','Escritura','Carga','descarga'];
    $a=null;
    foreach($roles_acceso as $r)
        $a .= $r['nombre_rol'].', ';
    $pdf->MultiCell(30,10,utf8_decode($a),1,'C',0);
```

Suponiendo que `$roles_acceso` exista y tenga el índice `nombre_rol` en todos sus elementos que a su vez son arrays.

Si lo que quieres es que te escriba los roles almacenados en `$roles`, entonces mejor haz algo así:

```
<?php
    $roles = ['Lectura','Escritura','Carga','descarga'];
    $a=implode(', ',$roles);
    $pdf->MultiCell(30,10,utf8_decode($a),1,'C',0);
```

Comment: Si ya habia resuelto mi duda como en tu ejemplo pero sin el foreach

Comment: Ya que existe, siempre queda más fácil de leer... :)